# Gleichzeitigkeit oder Nachzeitigkeit in diesem Satz?

Tags: tense

> Seitdem hat sich jedoch herumgesprochen, dass dieses Beispiel auf Stackexchange steht.

Dieses Beispiel (aus Kopierschutzgründen leicht abgewandelt) steht in der Duden-Grammatik unter der Verwendung von *seitdem* als Adverb mit Gleichzeitigkeit.
Doch die beiden Teilsätze nutzen doch unterschiedliche Zeitformen? Wieso gilt es als Gleichzeitigkeit?

Wieso muss es nicht so lauten, um Gleichzeitigkeit auszudrücken:

> Seitdem spricht sich jedoch herum, dass dieses Beispiel auf Stackexchange steht.

Referenz ist Dudenband 4 2009 Nr. 1770

Comment: Seitdem steht ... dort und seitdem hat es sich herumgesprochen. Ich verstehe das Problem nicht.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammatisch, bei Vergleich der benutzten Zeitformen, sieht es vielleicht auf den ersten Blick so aus, als müsste der Perfektsatz "es hat sich herumgesprochen" zeitlich vor dem Präsenssatz "dieses Beispiel [steht] auf Stackexchange" liegen, aber wenn man stattdessen inhaltlich darüber nachdenkt, wird klar, dass das nicht stimmt.

Dass ein Beispiel auf Stackexchange steht, kann sich ja nur herumsprechen, wenn es bereits der Fall ist. Das heißt, das Herumsprechen und das Auf-SE-Stehen sind beide zumindest *auch* über einen bestimmten Zeitraum gleichzeitig gewesen. Dieser Zeitraum liegt aus der Sicht des Sprechers in der Vergangenheit.

Der Dass-Nebensatz steht nur im Präsens, weil das Auf-SE-Stehen auch nach der Periode der Gleichzeitigkeit, um die es im Hauptsatz geht, noch anhält. Es fing früher an als der Hauptsatz, und es hält immer noch an.

Dein alternativer Vorschlag

> Seitdem spricht sich jedoch herum, dass dieses Beispiel auf Stackexchange steht.

drückt natürlich auch Gleichzeitigkeit aus, aber eben zusätzlich auch Gleichzeitigkeit mit der Zeit des Sprechers. Wenn man versucht, deinen Vorschlag bei Beibehaltung der Gleichzeitigkeit in die Vergangenheit zu setzen, kommt man genau beim Beispielsatz an, wenn das Auf-SE-Stehen auch nach dem Zeitraum der Gleichzeitigkeit weiter anhält.

> Seitdem hat sich jedoch herumgesprochen, dass dieses Beispiel auf Stackexchange steht.

Comment: Danke.
Ich habe zu sehr auf die Zeitformen geachtet.

Answer (score 0):

"Seitdem" im Bezug auf Gleichzeitigkeit zu benutzen, ist irreführend. Es bedeutet schließlich, ein in der Vergangenheit liegender Zeitpunkt startete eine Evolution/Entwicklung, die auch jetzt noch wirkt. Der begriffliche Unterschied in den Versionen ist aber offensichtlich: "Seitdem hat es sich ..herumgesprochen" bedeutet, die Allgemeinheit (der zum Beispiel Zeitung lesenden, informierten Bürger) hat es verstanden, und das "Herumsprechen" ist eher Vergangenheit, aber "Seitdem spricht sich jedoch herum" bedeutet, dieses ins Bewusstsein bringen dauert noch an, und man muß noch eine Zeitlang warten bis alle es wissen.